# Why are my tests not getting run in my TestCase subclass?

Tags: django, tdd

I am learning test driven development...

I wrote a test that should fail but it's not...

```
(env)glitch:ipals nathann$ ./manage.py test npage/
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

in npage/ I have tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from npage.models import Tip
import datetime


# Example


class TipTester(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print dir(self)
        Tip.objects.create(pk=1,
                           text='Testing',
                           es_text='Probando')

    def tips_in_spanish(self):
        my_tip = Tip.objects.get(pk=1)

        my_tip.set_language('es')

        self.assertEqual(my_tip.text, 'this does not just say \'Probando\'')
```

What am I doing wrong? I've read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/) but I still can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: I don't think you need the forward slash after npage in the command you're running either.

Comment: Apparently you can do it a lot of different ways, even isolating test cases within the app itself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: Well I just learned something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test functions need to start with test:

```
def test_tips_in_spanish(self):
```

Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/)

"When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase) in any file whose name begins with test, automatically build a test suite out of those test cases, and run that suite."

Comment: Note that the issue isn't so much that tests weren't failing, but that they weren't *running*.  "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize that also was meant for functions. 'in any file whose name begins with test'